# Fast and furious random reading of huge files

Tags: performance, file, dataset, large-data

I know that the question isn't new but I haven't found anything useful. In my case I have a 20 GB file and I need to read random lines from it. Now I have simple file index which contains line numbers and corresponding seek offsets. Also I disabled buffering when reading to read only the needed line.

And this is my code:

```
def create_random_file_gen(file_path, batch_size=0, dtype=np.float32, delimiter=','):
    index = load_file_index(file_path)

    if (batch_size > len(index)) or (batch_size == 0):
        batch_size = len(index)

    lines_indices = np.random.random_integers(0, len(index), batch_size)

    with io.open(file_path, 'rb', buffering=0) as f:
        for line_index in lines_indices:
            f.seek(index[line_index])
            line = f.readline(2048)
            yield __get_features_from_line(line, delimiter, dtype)
```

The problem is that it's extremely slow: reading of 5000 lines takes 89 seconds on my Mac(here I point to ssd drive). There is code I used for testing:

```
features_gen = tedlium_random_speech_gen(5000) # just a wrapper for function given above

i = 0
for feature, cls in features_gen:
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print("Got %d features" % i)

    i += 1

print("Total %d features" % i)
```

I've read something about files memory mapping but I don't really understand how it works: how the mapping works in essence and will it speed up the process or no.

So the main question what are the possible ways to speed up the process? The only way I see now is to read randomly not every line but blocks of lines.